# Enable email for every action for every one on mantis

Tags: email, mantis

I want to enable the email notification for every action on Mantis and these emails will be received by everyone. so can any one please let know how the email configuration should be?

I used settings like the following, but i am not getting any email for new bug and any other changes, i only receive emails if someone send me a reminder.

```
$g_enable_email_notification    = ON;

$g_default_notify_flags = array('reporter'  => ON,
                'handler'   => ON,
                'monitor'   => ON,
                'bugnotes'  => ON,
                'explicit'      => ON,
                'threshold_min' => NOBODY,
                'threshold_max' => NOBODY);
```

Comment: I have no any of these params in my config file. I've just went to the config in the admin panel, and set there everything. Maybe you can check with a test.php on your server, a `simple mail();` function is works. If not, then maybe you need to set an SMTP server in the config.

Comment: email is working fine. i am receiving the ticket reminder emails.

Comment: And what if you commented out this, and check on the admin for all privileges to all notification. And please remember, there is a setting called: `$g_email_receive_own = OFF;` Try to insert it into your file, and set it to `ON`

Answer (score 1):

You can do this from the Management area in Mantis. Follow these steps to have email notifications on all issue actions

1. Login to Mantis as *administrator*.
2. Select **All Projects** from the **Projects** drop down on the top-right
   corner
3. Click on **Manage** on the **Main menu (top)**
4. Click on **Manage Configuration**-->**E-mail Notifications**
5. Select all the checkboxes and **update** the configuration.

*Please note that there are no email notifications when you move an issue to another project.*